# Is there a public key encryption for permutations which is homomorphic under permutation composition?

Tags: public-key, homomorphic-encryption, permutation

I'm brainstorming an idea for extending our Latin square autotopism secret sharing scheme (proposed [here](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s10623-015-0123-1) [open access]) to a repairable scheme.  I seek a cryptographic method, which may or may not exist.

- We are encrypting permutations.  (For the application I have in mind, restricting to permutations of $\{1,2,\ldots,14\}$ would be fine.)
- It's a [public key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography) encryption method.  So I generate a public key $k$ and private key $p$, and I can distribute $k$ for others to encrypt with, but I decrypt with the private key $p$.

  So any permutation $\alpha$ is encrypted to $E_k(\alpha)$, say.
- It's homomorphic on permutation composition.  I.e., if $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are any two permutations, then $E_k(\alpha \beta)=E_k(\alpha) E_k(\beta)$.

Does such an $E$ exist?

For the application I have in mind, it doesn't need to be efficient computationally.

Comment: Are you using the full [symmetric group $S_n$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_group) or a subset? Since $14! < 2^{37}$ that seems like a small key space.

Comment: The full symmetric group.  At the moment, I'm at the "proof of concept" stage (brainstorming).  I don't know if it will be helpful in the end.

Comment: If you're wondering just about existence, check out [homomorphic shuffles](http://www0.cs.ucl.ac.uk/staff/J.Groth/JournalShuffle.pdf), particularly Section 2.2. It's not exactly your problem though (they are interested in proving correctness of shuffles).

Comment: Rebecca, is it not possible to find an isomorphism between the symmetric group you want to use and some group $(\mathbb{Z}_m, +)$? (Maybe by some theorem like the Cayley's one?). Because if it is possible, than you can just use "classic" homomorphic schemes like Paillier.

Comment: I doubt it; the symmetric group is non-abelian.